# How to generate vector tiles and how to display it in leaflet

Tags: vector, leaflet, tiles

My data consists of many elements and attibutes, so I can't send entire `json` to `client-side` because it's too slow reading and displaying data.

At this point I need to make **tiles** from data. I have worked with **tippecanoe**, and it's so good but it "only" generates *.mbtiles (vector data inside *.pbf), and Leaflet 1.0.2 can't work with this format, so I tried to extract into zoom folders z/x/y with **mbutil**, but it seems that resulted *.pbf tiles are not correct because I've tried with *Mapbox gl js* and doesn't work well.

So first question is:

someone know how can I generate *.pbf tiles correctly from geojson files? I've tried some of options showed here: [awesome-vector-tiles](https://github.com/mapbox/awesome-vector-tiles)

And someone know if there's some plugin for Leaflet 1.0.2 that can work with vector tiles in *.mbtiles, *.pbf or *.json?

I've tried with [mapbox-gl-leaflet](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet), *vectorgrid* and *tangram*.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt

Answer (score 3):

You can serve Mapbox vector tiles from a Tippecanoe generated `.mbtiles` file using [TileServer-GL](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl). Using Docker makes this task even easier.

Assuming you have already generated a file called `geo.mbtiles` using Tippecanoe in your current directory:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/tileserver-gl geo.mbtiles
```

This will spin up a server, and it will give you an endpoint that serves `.pbf` vector tiles. These can be rendered with Mapbox GL, Leaflet.VectorGrid, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tippecanoe with the -e option to generate *.pbf files in the proper directory structure. See https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe#output-tileset

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/tangrams/tangram

Tangram: WebGL Maps for Vector Data

you can display vector tiles using this JS library with leaflet

Thanks