# r - leaflet rendered custom map returns blank page

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I have followed some of the steps from https://www.milesmcbain.com/posts/vector-tiles/ to create a custom tiled map for use in `leaflet`, but the map is never rendered. Only a blank page shows up (both in the Web browser and in RStudio).

```
library(USA.state.boundaries)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

# load the state_boundaries_wgs84 data from USA.state.boundaries
data(state_boundaries_wgs84)

# convert from sf to geojson
st_write(state_boundaries_wgs84, "mp_state_boundaries_wgs84.geojson")
```

The following code (modified from [How to generate vector tiles and how to display it in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378922/how-to-generate-vector-tiles-and-how-to-display-it-in-leaflet) and the aforementioned link) was used to create a directory rather than a single mbtiles file:

```
tippecanoe -zg \
           -e mp_state_boundaries_wgs84 \
           --coalesce-densest-as-needed \
           --extend-zooms-if-still-dropping \
           mp_state_boundaries_wgs84.geojson
```

These are the futile attempts to render the custom map with leaflet:

```
m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles(urlTemplate = "https://{s}.ecoccs.com/mp_state_boundaries_wgs84/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf",
option = tileOptions(minZoom = 2, maxZoom = 5))
m


m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles(urlTemplate = "https://{s}.ecoccs.com/mp_state_boundaries_wgs84/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
option = tileOptions(minZoom = 2, maxZoom = 5))
m
```

What is the proper way to render the custom map in leaflet?